# AWK: How to Compare Two Variables with Regular Expression

Tags: awk, regular-expression

I have a line with colon separated values that I want process in awk. Lines are handled differently if variable `$4` contains varible `$3` at the begin.

So I wrote the expression: `$4 ~ /^$3/`, but unfortunaltely this does not work, it never matches. What's wrong, how can I use a variable in a regular expression pattern?

This is the full example:

```
green="$(tput setaf 2)"
red="$(tput setaf 1)"
yellow="$(tput setaf 3)"
normal="$(tput sgr0)"

stacks=$(docker stack ls --format='{{.Name}}')

for stack in ${stacks}; do
    status=$(docker stack ps --filter="desired-state=running" --format="{{.Name}}:{{.Node}}:{{.DesiredState}}:{{.CurrentState}}:{{.Error}}" ${stack})
    if test -z "$status"; then
        echo "${red}$stack$: disabled${normal}"
    else
        awk -F: '                                                                            
            $4 ~ /^$3/ {print "GOOD '"${green}"'" $1 ": " $4 "'"${normal}"'"}                
            $4 !~ /^$3/ {print "BAD '"${yellow}"'" $1 ": " $3 " ≠ " $4 $5 "'"${normal}"'"}   
        ' <<<${status}
    fi
done
```

Result is always `BAD`, e.g. here, line:

```
bind_bind.1:urknall:Running:Running 18 hours ago:
```

should print `GOOD`, but prints:

```
BAD bind_bind.1: Running ≠ Running 18 hours ago
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`/^$3/` is a regular expression that is [guaranteed to never match](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04_09) as it matches on records that have `3` after the end of the record (the `$` regular expression *anchor* operator matches at the end of the subject, not to be confused with the `$` `awk` operator that is used to dereference fields by number).

To test whether the third field occurs in the beginning of the fourth field, one could do either a regular expression match with `match()`, which will return the start position of the match (or -1 if no match was found):

```
awk -F ':' 'match($4, $3) == 1 { ..."GOOD"... ; next } { ..."BAD"... }'
```

or, for a string comparison,

```
awk -F ':' 'substr($4, 1, length($3)) == $3 { ..."GOOD"... ; next } { ..."BAD"... }'
```

Comment: The substr solution does exactly, what I tried to achieve, so I marked this as accepted answer, even though other answer also provide good approaches.

Answer (score 11):

You can put the regex on the right side of a `~` in a string, it doesn't have to be a `/.../` construct. (The difference might have been related to parsing the RE at runtime or at compile time, but I'm not sure.) And remember that in `awk`, the dollar sign doesn't mean variable expansion like in shell or Perl, so you need to concatenate `$3` to the rest of the string:

The first one matches, the second doesn't:

```
$ echo 'foo fo+' |awk '$1 ~ "^" $2'
foo fo+
$ echo 'foo o+' |awk '$1 ~ "^" $2'
$
```

`/^$2/` is taken as a regex with a literal `$2` in it, and the `$` is the end-of-line anchor. Since you can't have anything after the EOL, the RE can never match.

Comment: I was wondering how `/^$2/` would actually be interpreted. Perl would probably interpolate `$2` but `awk` is awfully opaque about what it does with it.

Comment: @Kusalananda, for `/^$2/`, there aren't really ambiguities. There's no way the `$` operator (`$2` is the `$` operator applied to 2, it's not a variable) would be invoked inside `/.../`, like there's no way `/1+2/` would invoke the `+` addition operator. There can be ambiguities with the `/` operator. For instance `print 1 /2/ 3` is not 1 concatenated with the result of the matching of the `2` regx against $0 concatenated with 3 (for which you'd need `1 (/2/) 3` but 1 divided by 2 divided by 3. And there are [ambiguities with backslash](http://austingroupbugs.net/bug_view_page.php?bug_id=1105).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Much appreciated. I believe that I might have expected `/$2/` to cause some sort of error or warning since it's impossible for it to match, but that might have been expecting too much magic from the underlying regexp library...

Comment: @Kusalananda, the `$2` ERE [is a valid POSIX ERE that is guaranteed to never match](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04_09).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas : it is interresting to know.  It is indeed what awk does (/$3/ will never match), but not what aix grep does (  printf '$3\n' | grep '^$3'  matches and prints `$3`). Is it because grep is not using ERE but another kind of regular expression matching?   (  grep -E '$3' uses ERE and does NOT match) And thus the "portable" way to insert a $ that someone wants to be taken literrally in a regular expression would be to enclose it in [] :    "[$]3" would match the 2 character string "$3" in most (all) regular expression (ERE, BRE, etc) engines?

Comment: @OlivierDulac, that looks like a yet another subtle difference between BRE and ERE. In "9.3.8 BRE Expression Anchoring" it says _"A <dollar-sign> shall be an anchor **when used as the last character** of an entire BRE."_, while in "9.4.9 ERE Expression Anchoring" it says _"A <dollar-sign> outside a bracket expression shall anchor the expression or subexpression it ends to the end of a string;"_ (regardless of where the `$` appears)

Comment: @OlivierDulac, by my reading of "9.3.3 BRE Special Characters" and "9.4.3 ERE Special Characters", `\$` should also match a literal dollar sign. Both say _"when preceded by a <backslash>, such a [special] character is [a BRE / an ERE] that matches the special character itself"_. Note that in Perl, you may need to escape the `$` even within a bracket expression, since otherwise it can be taken as a variable expansion.

Comment: @ilkkachu: thanks, indeed, I forgot that \ could help here also (I myself try to avoid using it, for readability reasons)